# How do I perform error handling with two files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

So , I am having two files , so to checks its validity  I am performing `try` and `except` two times . But I don't thinks this is a good method, can you suggest a better way?

Here is my code:

```
def form_density_dictionary(self,word_file,fp_exclude):
  self.freq_dictionary={}
  try:
      with open(fp_exclude,'r')as fp2:
          words_excluded=fp2.read().split() #words to be excluded stored in a list
          print("**Read file successfully :" + fp_exclude + "**")
          words_excluded=[words.lower() for words in words_excluded] # converted to lowercase

  except IOError:
      print("**Could not read file:", fp_exclude, " :Please check file name**")
      sys.exit()

  try:
      with open(word_file,'r') as file:
          print("**Read file successfully :" + word_file + "**")
          words_list=file.read()
          if not words_list:
              print("**No data in file:",word_file +":**")
              sys.exit()
          words_list=words_list.split()
          words_list=[words.lower() for words in words_list] # lowercasing entire list
      unique_words=list((set(words_list)-set(words_excluded)))

      self.freq_dictionary= {word:("%6.2f"%(float((words_list.count(word))/len(words_list))*100))  for word in unique_words}
      #print((len(self.freq_dictionary)))
  except IOError:
      print("**Could not read file:", word_file, " :Please check file name**")
      sys.exit()
```

Any other suggestion is also welcomed to make it more pythonic.

Comment: Two more ideas to make your code more "pythonic": first, use `format` instead of string concat `"**Read file successfully :" + fp_exclude + "**"` -> `"**Read file successfully: {} **".format(fp_exclude)`. Second, use built-in functions, like `map`: `words_list = [words.lower() for words in words_list]` -> `list(map(str.lower, words))`

Comment: yeah , thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is the lack of consistency and readability: in some lines you indent with 4 spaces, on others you only use two; in some places you put a space after a comma, in others you don't, in most places you don't have spaces around the assignment operator (`=`)...

Be consistent and make your code readable. The most commonly used formatting is to use four spaces for indenting and to always have a space after a comma but even more important than that is to be consistent, meaning that whatever you choose, stick with it throughout your code. It makes it much easier to read for everyone, including yourself.

Here are a few other things I think you could improve:

- Have a single exception handling block instead of two.
- You can also open both files in a single line.
- Even better, combine both previous suggestions and have a separate method to read data from the files, thus eliminating code repetition and making the main method easier to read.
- For string formatting it's preferred to use `.format()` instead of `%`. Check this out: https://pyformat.info/
- Overall try to avoid repetition in your code. If there's something you're doing more than once, extract it to a separate function or method and use that instead.

Here's your code quickly modified to how I'd probably write it, and taking these things into account:

```
import sys


class AtifImam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq_dictionary = {}

    def form_density_dictionary(self, word_file, exclude_file):
        words_excluded = self.read_words_list(exclude_file)
        words_excluded = self.lowercase(words_excluded)

        words_list = self.read_words_list(word_file)
        if len(words_list) == 0:
            print("** No data in file: {} **".format(word_file))
            sys.exit()

        words_list = self.lowercase(words_list)

        unique_words = list((set(words_list) - set(words_excluded)))

        self.freq_dictionary = {
            word: ("{:6.2f}".format(
                float((words_list.count(word)) / len(words_list)) * 100))
            for word in unique_words
            }

    @staticmethod
    def read_words_list(file_name):
        try:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
                data = file.read()
                print("**  Read file successfully: {} **".format(file_name))
                return data.split()
        except IOError as e:
            print("** Could not read file: {0.filename} **".format(e))
            sys.exit()

    @staticmethod
    def lowercase(word_list):
        return [word.lower() for word in word_list]
```

Comment: yeah , this will be much better . Thank you  ^_^

Comment: But , If you will see my code , I am opening two files , so how to handle two files in same try ?

Comment: I am opening the two files as well. There are two calls to the `read_words_list` method, one for `words_excluded` and another for `words_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions thrown that involve a file system path have a `filename` attribute that can be used instead of explicit attributes `word_file` and `fp_exclude` as you do.

This means you can wrap these IO operations in the same `try-except` and use the `exception_instance.filename` which will indicate in which file the operation couldn't be performed.

For example:

```
try:
    with open('unknown_file1.py') as f1, open('known_file.py') as f2:
        f1.read()
        f2.read()
except IOError as e:
    print("No such file: {0.filename}".format(e))
```

Eventually prints out:

```
No such file: unknown_file1.py
```

While the opposite:

```
try:
    with open('known_file.py') as f1, open('unknown_file2.py') as f2:
        f1.read()
        f2.read()
except IOError as e:
    print("No such file: {0.filename}".format(e))
```

Prints out:

```
No such file: unknown_file2.py
```

Comment: Is there any way to let user know which file doen't exist  ? According to your answer the error statement prints based on the order in  which we open the file ?

Comment: When the exception is caught, you print out the filename. The first file to throw an `IOError` will be the one for which the user is notified. Since you `sys.exit` in cases where `IOError` is thrown, the functionality I provided is similar to yours, only wrapped up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To be more 'pythonic' you could use something what is callec Counter, from collections library.

```
from collections import Counter


def form_density_dictionary(self, word_file, fp_exclude):
    success_msg = '*Read file succesfully : {filename}'
    fail_msg = '**Could not read file: {filename}: Please check filename'
    empty_file_msg = '*No data in file :{filename}:**'
    exclude_read = self._file_open(fp_exclude, success_msg, fail_msg, '') 
    exclude = Counter([word.lower() for word in exclude_read.split()])
    word_file_read = self._file_open(word_file, success_msg, fail_msg, empty_file_msg)
    words = Counter([word.lower() for word in word_file_read.split()])
    unique_words = words - excluded
    self.freq_dictionary = {word: '{.2f}'.format(count / len(unique_words)) 
                            for word, count in unique_words.items()}
```

Also it would be better if you would just create the open_file method, like:

```
def _open_file(self, filename, success_msg, fails_msg, empty_file_msg):
    try:
       with open(filename, 'r') as file:
           if success_msg:
               print(success_msg.format(filename= filename))
           data = file.read()
           if empty_file_msg:
               print(empty_file_msg.format(filename= filename))
           return data
    except IOError:
           if fail_msg:
               print(fail_msg.format(filename= filename))
           sys.exit()
```

Comment: I kind of change the structure (add one, extra method to handle the file opening)

Comment: yeah , that appear much better .  Thank you